# How to design an efficient StartTime and EndTime picker in React tailwind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, tailwind-css

[image]

I have to implement a time picker in the above format ( hh:mm:ss ) . Right now I have made it so that hour , minutes and seconds can be picked from dropdown .

To prevent the user from picking End time earlier than start time -

- When user picks an hour in start time and  same in end time , a filter array containing eligible minutes is rendered for end time picker (same goes for minutes and seconds )
- When user picks end time hour greater than starting time hour , all 60 minutes and 60 seconds are rendered for end time picker

I am handling it's state in following way -

```
const [startingTime, setStartingTime] = useState({
    hours: "",
    minutes: "",
    seconds: "",
});
const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState({
    hours: "",
    minutes: "",
    seconds: "",
});
```

Is their any other approach so that i can make it efficient and clean